# Access requires table relink of SQL Server table every time CurrentDB is opened

Tags: sql-server, key, ms-access-2007, primary-key, subform

I have an Access database that uses SQL Server as its backend. One table is the data for a subform which is loaded into a parent form and displayed in the parent forma as a datasheet. The datasheet is intended to have rows added to it by users.

The subform backend table is defined in SQL Server with a primary key `[ID]`. The primary key is linked to the `Master ID` of the current record displayed in the parent form. The subform is then filtered by the relationship between the subform table primary key and the parent form master ID. Nothing unusual here.

The problem that when the parent form is first opened in Access the subform is cannot have records added. It is not until the linked table manager is opened and the backend table is RELINKED can the user add records to the subform. Oddly enough, when relinking the table I am always prompted for the primary key of the table even though it is defined in SQL Server.

The subform has the following settings

```
Data Entry:   Yes
Allow Additions:  Yes
Allow Deletions:  Yes
Allow Edits:  Yes
Allow Filters:  Yes
Record Locks:  No Locks
```

Here is the CREATE TABLE for the backend table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProjectHealth](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Project Health] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [ProjectID] [int] NULL,
    [Entered By] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Again, the RELINK solves the problem. But a VBA `TableDef.Refreshlink` call does not do the trick. Even if I reset the primary key from VBA.

My suspicion is that I have modified some value in the subform settings that have caused this problem which started happening after a few days of normal behavior. Thanks in advance for any suggestions you can provide.

Comment: Very strange. Once the frontend is in this state, can you edit/add rows in the linked table directly? Also please add the CREATE TABLE for the problematic table.

Comment: Andre.  CREATE TABLE added per your suggestion.  I am beginning to think I need to add a constraint to this table.

Comment: Andre.  Adding a constraint on the backend table by RMB on the column and setting the primary key in the SSMS table editor did the trick.  Thank you for your suggestion which lead me to compare the CREATE TABLE to other tables in this database!  That is a troubleshooting step that never occurred to me.

Comment: Yes, every server table you want to link in Access needs to have a primary key, and Access must automatically recognize the PK when linking the table. Otherwise you are going to have trouble editing that table.